# LT1054 wrong output

Tags: power-supply, negative-voltage, switched-capacitor

I'm using a LT1054 to generate a negative voltage to power my OpAmp's. I used the circuit described in figure TA03 of the datasheet. My **Vin** is 15 V and my **R1** and **R2** are 20k and 220k respectively. With that configuration it should output -12 V, but it is outputing -15 V. What am I doing wrong?

Datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1054-1054L.pdf

My circuit:

[image]

My chip:

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147204/discussion-on-question-by-cicero-zanette-lt1054-wrong-output); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.